# In MongoDB, how to clone a column in a collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a way to add a new column in a collection which is clone of an existing column in the same collection?

**PersonTable**

```
_id | Name
1   | John
```

**Result**

```
_id | Name | Name(cloned)
1   | John | John
```

Hopefully without a `foreach` loop.

Comment: You can use [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) aggregation here

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet this will create another collection out of the current one, right?

Comment: Right but you can replace the name of the collection after that... And your column name should also be different for that (`"nameCloned"`)

Comment: This is risky I think, what if a document got changed during this operation? Can't I simply use `Update` somehow?

Comment: Did the below solution work for you? please let me know

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyWinzlet.. I am disappointed with missing such a simple feature in MongoDB. Your solution is risky for me scince data might get changed during the read operation, plus how do you think it will perform in big collections! not sure if this is the best way to handle it

Comment: In my aspects the `$out` aggregation should work here but I have never checked it for the huge database so not 100% sure about it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`bulkWrite`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) operation

```
const persons = await PersionTable.find({})

const updateTable = await PersionTable.bulkWrite(
  persons.map((person) => {
  person.clonedName = person.name
    return({
      updateOne : {
        filter: { _id: person._id },
        update: { $set: person }
      }
    })
  })
)
```